# Как можно сделать список игнорированных людей ботом

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я хочу сделать команду **игнор** в боте. Типо например я пишу 'игнор (участника помечаю), после он добавляется в список игнорированных людей и бот после не реагирует на него.
Код, как пример:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.check(moderator) #не обращайте внимания
async def игнор(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    await ignoruser.append(member.id)
```

Как можно сделать код или улучшить?
А так же как сделать, чтобы люди выводились из списка, ну типо 'разигнор, как разбан.?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам посоветовал использовать БД, т.к. списки не устойчивые, и при перезапуске бота, он пропадёт.
Но если вы всё же решили использовать списки, то вот код на **ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ** и **УДАЛЕНИЕ** из списка:

```py
ignoruser = []

@bot.command()
@commands.check(moderator) # не обращайте внимания
async def игнор(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is not None:
        await ignoruser.append(member.id)
        await ctx.reply('Успешно!')
    else:
        await ctx.reply(f'Правильное использование команды:\n`{ctx.prefix}игнор <member>')

@bot.command()
@commands.check(moderator) # не обращайте внимания
async def раз_игнор(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is not None:
        await ignoruser.remove(member.id)
        await ctx.reply('Успешно!')
    else:
        await ctx.reply(f'Правильное использование команды:\n`{ctx.prefix}раз_игнор <member>')
```

Проверьте, если что отпишите.

Comment: У меня вопрос, а что такое БД? я просто не оч хорош в терминах.(еще код не проверил)

Comment: БД - база данных